# how does root CA restricts website access without corporate vpn connection

Tags: network-programming, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

when connected to a corporate vpn or in a corporate wifi environment, the corporation network uses a proxy for all http traffic. When connect to a personal wifi and not connected to the corporate vpn, all internet connection will display a page where it says "please connect to corporate vpn before you can visit any website". There is a McAfee root CA also being added to the system that allows this to happen. How does this work behind the scene?

the deployed service to client laptop is called McAfee SaaS Web Operations, I just wonder how it works to make root CA redirecting traffic

Comment: There's probably a (local) proxy installed as well that redirects all traffic.  When connected to the vpn, it redirects to the vpn and when not connected it serves up the "please connect" messages.

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks! Is there a way to check for that on OSX, https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-proxy-settings-network-preferences-mac-mchlp2591/12.0/mac/12.0
for this proxy settings I see a global.pac file within the advanced setting for the personal network, but that is for company proxy and exclusions? or the local proxy could also be configured there as well?